# TypeError: this. is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola estoy usando un `Alertify` pero cargando desde `index.html` dentro de `React JS`, todo estaba bien, como variable global, usando `alertify[error,success]` no hay problema, incluso ejecutar peticiones dentro de `confirm`, como `Ajax, axios` normal, pero no reconoce otros metodod dentro de `React JS` ni el `estado`

> TypeError: this.Apertura is not a function

```
Abrecaja(da, ca) {
    alertify.confirm("Apertura de Caja", "La Caja de Apertura con los montos puestos anteriormente", function () {
        this.Apertura();
        this.setState({ abierto: !this.state.abierto });
    }, function () {
        alertify.success("Verifique sus montos");
    });
    //axios.post("apertura/caja/" + ca, { data: da }).then(res => this.Apertura());
}
Apertura() {
    this.props.ocaja();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que re definir o volver a declarar `this` en una nueva variable, así:

```
Abrecaja(da, ca) {
    var $this = this;
    alertify.confirm("Apertura de Caja", "La Caja de Apertura con los montos puestos anteriormente", function () {
        $this.Apertura();
        $this.setState({ abierto: !this.state.abierto });
    }, function () {
        alertify.success("Verifique sus montos");
    });
    //axios.post("apertura/caja/" + ca, { data: da }).then(res => $this.Apertura());
}
Apertura() {
    this.props.ocaja();
}
```